# Check if a value exists in MySQL with php

Tags: php, mysql

I've been looking around stackoverflow and wasn't able to ever find a way that'd actually work. I have a simple php application

```
//Database credentials
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$database = "database";

// Create connection to database
$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection for errors
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("<h1>Connection to database failed: " . $db->connect_error) . "</h1>";
};

$username = $json['statuses'][0]['user']['screen_name'];
$userid = $json['statuses'][0]['user']['id_str'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM log WHERE userid='" . $userid . "' LIMIT 1";

if ($db->query($sql)->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<h4>This user already exists</h4>";
} else {
    //Put the userid into the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO log (userid) VALUES ('" . $userid . "')";

    if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "<h4>Added " . $username . " to the database</h4>";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $db->error;
    }
}
```

Currently it seems to be hit or miss. It'll work sometimes, other times a record will exist, and it'll still insert the userid again creating duplicates.

[image: phpmyadmin]

Comment: Adding screenshots for textual data is usually a bad plan, especially as people can't cut and paste from these to provide answers.

Comment: add unique index on `userid` - problem solved

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: @Dagon I was wanting to get this to work properly without doing that.

Comment: using unique index is VERY proper

Comment: @Dagon It should be working regardless though, without using a unique index. It's really just a bug that bothers me, I know I can accomplish it like that, but I'd rather the php work as intended.

Comment: i think you know how hard it would be for strangers to debug code that *sometimes* works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like said @tadman Your code is BAD. Data from variable `$json` is directly inserted into query - this is not good...

Simple test:

I set :

```
 $userid = "111111111a";
```

query:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM log WHERE userid='111111111a' LIMIT 1";
```

return TRUE because, this user doesn't exists in db,

or

```
 $userID ='111111111\' OR \'1=1';
```

query:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM log WHERE userid='111111111' OR '1=1' LIMIT 1";
```

return TRUE because 1=1 is always true.

If column `userid` is INT type, $userid value is converted to 111111111 and inserted into `log` table

Comment: Hah! I'm actually pretty dumb. The problem was I had values larger than the int MySQL can handle. I really appreciate your response!

Also, this won't ever be publicly facing, it won't even be on a web server, it's meant for a cronjob to run every so often and pick a user ID.